# jmeter replace subsequent requests with response from initial request

Tags: jmeter

I am thinking of using Jmeter Access Log Sampler to replay tomcat access log or even normal http sampler with a CSV.

What we have in the log is

url1?CallId=1&otherParam=value

url1?CallId=1&otherParam=value&CONTEXT_ID=123435

url1?CallId=1&otherParam=value&CONTEXT_ID=123435&somemoreParam=etc..

url1?CallId=2&otherParam=value

url1?CallId=2&otherParam=value&CONTEXT_ID=67859

When the first request sent to the server without the CONTEXT_ID the server will do a lot of stuff and create a context id for that CallId and return it in the response. Subsequent calls to the server for the same CallId need to have the this same CONTEXT_ID on the URL. Context_IDs from access logs server will not exist in the target server so I can't just use it as is.

Is there a way to capture the response from the initial request for a given CallId and replace CONTEXT_ID for subsequent requests that contains the same callId?

Thanks & regards
voki

Answer (score 0):

Extract it with:

```
&CONTEXT_ID=([^"]+)
```

Re-use it:

```
${YourParamName}
```

See also http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

Comment: Thank you Johan. I guess I was confusing at the concurrent requests that will be executed by multiple threads. How do I make sure certain subsequent requests are replaced with correct CONTEXTID based on a CallId?